# How to Parse string Mutiple Times in Delphi use System.Json

Tags: json, delphi

```
var json := TJSONObject.Create;

json.Parse(TEncoding.Default.GetBytes('{"a":"va","b":1009}'), 0);
Memo1.Lines.Add(json.GetValue<string>('a'));

json.Parse(TEncoding.Default.GetBytes('{"a":"vab","bb":1119}'), 0);
Memo1.Lines.Add(json.GetValue<string>('a'));

json.Free;
```

Memo1 displays `va` twice, not `va` and `vab`.

Comment: is there have func like clear .i want parse many times with diff string in same function

Comment: Some general advice, try to use an interface the way it is designed to be used, and not the way you imagine it should have been designed.

Comment: You should be using `TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue()` instead of `TJSONObject.Parse()` directly.

Comment: @陈发条 "*is there have func like clear*" - `TJSONObject` does not have a `Clear()` method. You could try using `TJSONObject.RemovePair()` in a loop, though.

Comment: @David Heffernan  TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue()  return also need free is right?

Answer (score 0):

`TJSONObject.Parse()` adds the parsed content to the existing object, preserving any values that already exist. You are meant to use `TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue()` instead when parsing new documents, eg:

```
var value := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue('{"a":"va","b":1009}');
try
  var json := value as TJSONObject; 
  Memo1.Lines.Add(json.GetValue<string>('a'));
finally
  value.Free;
end;

value := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue('{"a":"vab","bb":1119}');
try
  var json := value as TJSONObject;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(json.GetValue<string>('a'));
finally
  value.Free;
end;
```

Comment: this lib is so confuse .var Json:=Tjsonobject.Parse()  json.clear; json.parse()  this is right way....Like other language.system.json is more complex than thid party lib

Comment: `TJSONObject.Parse()` returns an `Integer` not a `TJSONObject`, and `TJSONObject` does not have a `Clear()` method.